# Adding a string to a listbox results in weird characters

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I have made a function that send strings to listbox using WIN32

```
char data[] = "abcd";

addToList(hWnd,data);

void addToList(HWND hWnd,char data[] ){
  SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_LISTBOX),LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)data);    
}
```

when I execute this it's send data to list box but the problem they appeared in weird characters, I have tried wchar_t also but the problem still issued

Comment: What weird characters? Is it chinese? In which case your program is Unicode, `SendMessage` is `SendMessageW` and `wchar_t data[] = L"abcd"` will solve the problem?

Comment: did you try debugging with a break-point at the window procedure to see if the LPARAM is correct?

Comment: Your code cannot be both C and C++. Please pick one.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should be checking your API calls for errors. You need to check the return values of all your calls to API functions.

That said, given the code in the question,

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_LISTBOX),LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)data);
```

If that results in an item being added to the list box, then it means that `GetDlgItem` did indeed return a valid window handle, and `data` did indeed point to valid memory. In which case the only explanation for what you report is that the text encoded did not match.

So, we can assume that the `SendMessage` macro evaluates to `SendMessageW`. And since you are passing ANSI encoded text, that mismatch explains the symptoms. The function treats the text as UTF-16 encoded.

One obvious solution is to use `SendMessageA` instead. However, a better solution, in my view, would be to pass UTF-16 encoded data.

```
wchar_t data[] = L"abcd";
....
void addToList(HWND hWnd, const wchar_t *data)
{
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_LISTBOX), LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)data);    
}
```

Obviously your code would add in the error checking that I mentioned at the start.

Comment: +1, isn't there a windowsx wrapper for this, or a control macro that catches the invalid character pointer? Been a *long* time since I did this. just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig Are you thinking of [`ListBox_AddString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856426.aspx)?

Comment: thank you, that's a good answer but i still have a problem because `wchar_t data` variable must be contain data from `float variable` and i don't know how to cast ! how can i solve it?

Comment: Well I don't know. That's a different question completely. When you ask that question, make sure you pick your language. C and C++ are quite different.